# SQL INNER JOIN fix

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this sql statement:

```
SELECT 
  e.id AS event_id, e.title, e.date, e.category, e.place, e.minAge, e.maxAge,
  p.id, p.name, p.coor, p.nz,
  a.user, a.event, COUNT(a.user) AS attending,
  i.user_id, i.event_id
FROM events AS e
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.event = e.id
LEFT JOIN places p ON p.id = e.place
LEFT JOIN invited_friends i ON ( i.event_id = e.id ) AND ( i.user_id = 0 )
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY attending DESC
```

This statement selects events from table events and join some tables. everything is good so far. 
I have another table called: `invited_friends`.

```
event_id    bigint(20)    
user_id     int(11)   
owner       tinyint(1)
```

This table stores the user ids that invited to event.

The problem is that not every event is a private event, not every event got invited friends... the way I can tell if event is private or not is the column: **category** in event table, if it = 4 then it is a private event.

My inner join works, but it ignores all the public events because they have no invited friends.

How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't understand, what is the desired output? just private events, or what?

Comment: left join instead of inner join for invite_Friends?

Comment: The output desired is all of the events, but if the event is private then the current user need to be invited or else it will ignore it: like my inner join: ``INNER JOIN invited_friends i ON ( i.event_id = e.id ) AND ( i.user_id = 0 )``. left join is good but it doesnt solve my problem because it still gives me private event that the current user is not invited to

Comment: post it in you question, got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
FROM events AS e
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.event = e.id
LEFT JOIN places p ON p.id = e.place
LEFT JOIN invited_friends i ON ( i.event_id = e.id ) AND ( i.user_id = 0 )

WHERE category != 4  or i.event_id is not null

...
```

Comment: left join is good but it doesnt solve my problem because it still gives me private event that the current user is not invited to

Comment: sorry i posted before i wrote the WHERE part - but i'm not sure about what would be null if the user is not invited ;))

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand the problem, then. Just make the the INNER JOIN a LEFT JOIN. It will work as it does now, and if there are no invited friends, then it will fill the invited_friends portion with null's. This will make it so that the public events with no friends are populated...just with no friends.

Comment: left join is good but it doesnt solve my problem because it still gives me private event that the current user is not invited to

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` on invited_friends rather than a straight `INNER JOIN.`

That should give you the result you want.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

Comment: ??I im in the understaing that a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is EXACTLY the same as a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: SO why don't you just UNION it with a list of public events?

SELECT e.id AS event_id, e.title, e.date, e.category, e.place, e.minAge, e.maxAge,
    p.id, p.name, p.coor, p.nz,
    a.user, a.event, COUNT(a.user) AS attending,
    i.user_id, i.event_id

    FROM events AS e

    LEFT JOIN attendance a ON a.event = e.id

    LEFT JOIN places p ON p.id = e.place

    INNER JOIN invited_friends i ON ( i.event_id = e.id ) AND ( i.user_id = 0 )


    GROUP BY e.id
    ORDER BY attending DESC
UNION
(query to select just public events)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: left join is good but it doesnt solve my problem because it still gives me private event that the current user is not invited to